# How can I alias returned values in a query?

Tags: oracle

I have a query that ultimately will return a column that might have the value "1", "2", or "3", where 1 means RED, 2 means BLUE, and 3 means GREEN.

How can I modify the query so instead of returning 1, 'RED' is returned, for 2 'BLUE' is returned, etc

I want my result to be something like:

**COLOR**

RED

RED

GREEN

BLUE

Instead of :

**COLOR**

1

1

3

2

Comment: show us the query! (however, [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) or [case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) should meet your need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Decode(MyField, 1, 'RED'
                       2, 'BLUE'
                       3, 'GREEN'
                          'UNDEFINED' as myfieldColor

FROM myTable
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, and I cannot mark it as answered for 5 more minutes!

Comment: I'm not worried about it.  Just happy to help.  Eran's suggestion isn't a bad one if you're going to have to do this multiple times.  Foreign key to a table which has those colors as MyFieldColorType or something like that allows for flexibility in new colors without having to change code (SQL).  but if your list of 'colors' is finite, then this is a reasonable solution (Decode)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, and more standards conformant:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MyField = 1 THEN 'RED'
            WHEN MyField = 2 THEN 'BLUE'
            WHEN MyField = 3 THEN 'GREEN'
            ELSE 'UNDEFINED'
       EMD myfieldColor
FROM myTable;
```

It's also more flexible, as you can use a wider assortment of SQL in the WHEN clause. For example:

```
WHEN MyField = 2 AND Lang = 'SPANISH' THEN 'AZUL'
```

Comment: perfectly viable solution (also indicated case in the comments section and provided a link.  Up to OP to do some reading and determine which they like to use and why.)

Comment: Didn't even see the comment :-) Should have been part of your answer!

Comment: Probably, but I tend to put actual samples in answers and theory in comments.